# Mysql conditional to select a value or its inverse

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to extract a value or its inverse from database. I would like to find a way to do the if statement in SQL, not in PHP.

My table looks like : id, rate, from_value, to_value

I have $from_value and $to_value variables, and would like to extract the corresponding rate value or its inverse.

I would like to

```
SELECT `rate` if `from_value` = $from_value and `to_value` = $to_value
```

or

```
SELECT (1/`rate`) if `from_value` = $to_value AND `to_value` = $from_value
```

with only one request.

I have searched a lot of ways to do that with CASE, IF, but I didn't find a working solution.
I probably missed something. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a portable method using `CASE`.  I have it returning `NULL` if *neither* condition is met.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN `from_value` = $from_value AND `to_value` = $to_value THEN rate
    WHEN `from_value` = $to_value AND `to_value` = $from_value THEN (1.0 / rate)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS rate
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that. I thought the WHEN x AND y didn't work. (it was because I precised a CASE `from_value` !!)

Answer (score 1):

Updated `IF` solution:

```
SELECT IF(from_value = $from_value AND to_value = $to_value, rate,
    IF(from_value = $to_value AND to_value = $from_value, (1.0 / rate), NULL)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: In that case, **Michael**'s answer is solid.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I cannot vote up 2 replies, but you answers the question.